# Null value appearing while passing string value from JSP to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Upload jsp file...start from here..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <form id="myservlet" method="POST" action="uploadServlet2" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            User Name:<input type="text" name="userName" /><br/><br/>
                      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>



        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet class file

```
package net.codejava.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class uploadServlet2
 */
@WebServlet("/uploadServlet2")

public class uploadServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String s=request.getParameter("userName");
        System.out.println("Print " +s);


    }

}
```

username value is not displaying and getting null value....Plz help me ..
Is there any problem in server version..i tried and googled but not working..
Using apache 8.5 server and servlet 3.0

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" --> This parameter is generally used for file uploading. So,Don't use this parameter. and try once ...

Comment: Its not working..still null value is appearing

Comment: Please check this example. https://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-registration-form-in-servlet

Answer (score 0):

Remove enctype if you are not uploading file

```
<form id="myservlet" method="POST" action="uploadServlet2" >
```

Comment: Still null value is appearing ...

Comment: its showing only "Print "?

Comment: noo....showing like "Print null"  appaering in the console